# how to disable the blank field in select rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select

I'm trying to disable a field inside a select input.
There is no problem for the standard field:
(this disable the field 'one')

```
= f.input_field :job, collection: %w[one two three], disabled: 1, include_blank: 'Select one', required: true
```

What i would like to do now is to disable the blank field after a user selected an other field. I tryed this:

```
= f.input_field :job, collection: %w[one two three], disabled: 0, include_blank: 'Select one', required: true
```

But it didn't work... any idea ?

Thanks for your help and your time :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable blank value we use `disabled: ""` and to select it before user selects anything we use `selected: ""`. Notice that it works with `prompt` option instead of `include_blank` only.

```
= f.input_field :name, collection: %w[one two three], disabled: "", selected: "", prompt: 'Select one', required: true
```